# Find the probability that all four suits occur among the cards selected.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a problem from the book by Daniel Marcus, Combinatorics: A problem-oriented approach.

```
C59. A card is selected at random from a standard 52-card deck. The suit
(H, S, D, or C) is recorded and the card is replaced in the deck. This is done
a total of seven times. Find the probability that all four suits occur among the
cards selected. (Hint: Count sequences of suits.)
```

The total number of sequences is $52^7$. I think the total number of sequences where all four suits occur is $52^4\cdot 39\cdot 26\cdot 13$.

So the probability should be $$(52^4\cdot 39\cdot 26\cdot 13)/52^7$$

There is no answer in the book so I'm not sure if I'm correct or not!

Comment: Can the problem be reduced to choosing a card from a four-card deck, one of each suit?  Do the results match?

Comment: Well yes I tried it that way. It gives the same result.

Comment: If $10$ cards are drawn and replaced instead of $7$, would your reasoning lead to a probability of $(52^7\cdot39\cdot26\cdot13)/52^{10}$?  If so, think about what that means!

Comment: This is the Coupon Collector's Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ${7\brace4}=350$ ways to put seven labelled items into exactly four unlabelled bags.

So there are $4!\cdot{7\brace 4}=8400$ sequences of suits with the property that all suits appear.

This gives a probability of $\frac{8400}{4^7}\approx 51.27\%$.

Comment: While your solution is correct, it might be clearer if you explained that $$\{{7 \atop 4}\}$$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: You can get the braces symbol with `{{n}\brace{k}}` for ${n\brace k}$.

Answer (score 2):

Applying [inclusion/exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry:

$$P\left(H\cap S\cap D\cap C\right)=$$$$1-P\left(H^{c}\cup S^{c}\cup D^{c}\cup C^{c}\right)=1-\binom{4}{1}P\left(H^{c}\right)+\binom{4}{2}P\left(H^{c}\cap S^{c}\right)-\binom{4}{3}P\left(H^{c}\cap S^{c}\cap D^{c}\right)$$

Here $P(H^c)=\left(\frac34\right)^7$, $P\left(H^{c}\cap S^{c}\right)=\left(\frac12\right)^7$ and $P\left(H^{c}\cap S^{c}\cap D^c\right)=\left(\frac14\right)^7$

and this results in: $$P\left(H\cap S\cap D\cap C\right)=\frac{525}{1024}\approx0.5127$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I did this problem again using the T-numbers mentioned in the book and got this result. This feels far more accurate. I was just getting confused because of the term "standard 52-card deck"!